# Swift 2nd function calls 1st and can't understand why

Tags: function, swift, xcode6

Trying to make simple app with Xcode 6. Row of switches that increase sum of count by one or two. I'm stuck on the start, for some reason my 2nd func actHTA() runs the 1st fund actInsuffCor() too messing up my count. Funny thing is I just yesterday coded a similar app with no problems and I have copied the exact form from that and still can't get it working.

The println("switch...") are my diagnostic lines, when I switch actInsuffCor switch, it prints "1 switch on/off" depending on where it starts but switch actHTA prints "2 switch on/off" and then "1 switch on/off" too and thats not what I meant to do.

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func actInsuffCor(sender: AnyObject) {
    if swInsuffCor.on {
        ++summa
        println("1 switch on")
        } else {
        --summa
        println("1 switch off")
    }
}
@IBAction func actHTA(sender: AnyObject) {
    if swHTA.on {
        ++summa
        println("2 switch on")
        } else {
        --summa
        println("2 switch off")
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please add some image. Is it possibile that you connected the button to the incorrect IBAction?

Comment: Wow, you got it right on the first try. I had connected my 2nd fund to both switches. I'm such an idiot...

Comment: I can rewrite my comment as an answer, so you can accept it... ok?

Comment: Answer wrote, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possibile that you connected the button to the incorrect IBAction?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @NKN Despite the fact this seems only an advice, actually it IS the answer to question, as you can read in comments above!